# How to handle errors and retries in spring-kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

This is a question related to :
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/575

I'm using spring-kafka 1.3.7 and transactions in a read-process-write cycle.
For this purpose, I should use a KTM on the spring kafka container to enable transaction on the whole listener process and automatic handling the transaction id based on the partition for zombie fencing(1.3.7 changes).

If I understand well from the issue #575, I can not use a RetryTemplate in a container when using a transaction manager.

How am I supposed to handle errors and retries in a such case ? 
The default behavior with transaction is infinite retries ? This seems really dangerous. An unexpected exception might simply block the whole process in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upcoming 2.2 release adds recovery to the `DefaultAfterRollbackProcessor` - so you can stop retrying after some number of attempts.

[Docs Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new-part.html#_listener_container_changes), [PR here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/764).

It also provides an optional mechanism to send the failed record to a dead-letter topic.

If you can't move to 2.2 (release candidate due at the end of this week, with GA in October), you can provide a custom `AfterRollbackProcessor` with similar functionality.

**EDIT**

Or, you could add code to your listener (or its error handler) to keep track of how many times the same record has been delivered, and handle the error in your listener, or its listener-level error handler.

Comment: Or you can use a listener error handler to give up after some number of attempts.

Comment: This isnt compatible with spring-kafka 1.x ? We are using springboot 1 and migrating to springboot2 is complicated

Comment: No; it's a new feature in 2.2; for earlier versions you need logic in your listener to somehow deal with repeatedly failing records.